# LibGDX–Fullscreen with 1280-720 resolution

Tags: java, libgdx, fullscreen

So, I'm making a FNAF clone type game, and I'm trying to use the `OrthographicCamera` class in libGdx, and I'm trying to make a game with a 1280x720 res, but, most monitors don't support that resolution in fullscreen, and so  my [code](http://pastie.org/10434876) keeps [crashing](http://pastie.org/10434883). How do I make a fullscreen game, without stretching or compromising resolution, preferably without black bars on the sides and/or top and bottom of the screen? 1280x960 is also fine for my purposes, and is compatible with most monitors, but libGDX automatically stretches it to a funky resolution. How do I fix that?

Comment: Well, you're going to have to either stretch or use black bars some of the time because monitors won't match the 16/9 ratio that 1280x720 expects. Have you tried not mucking with the width and height when you initialize, but then using a ScalingViewport for rendering once you have?

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to handle this problem. Libgdx has a different `Viewport` implementation for pretty much all of them (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports).

Comment: 1280x960 is also fine for my purposes, and is compatible with most monitors, but libGDX automatically stretches it. How do I fix that?